# Predicting NER with BertForTokenClassification model

Tags: neural-network, nlp, prediction, bert-language-model

I have built my model using this tutorial on NER with bert:

https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/named-entity-recognition-with-bert/#resources

However, I could not figure out how to parse in a input data into the model to predict its ner value.

The following links are some of the resources I have looked through

[How should properly formatted data for NER in BERT look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220842/how-should-properly-formatted-data-for-ner-in-bert-look-like)

https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertfortokenclassification

Comment: Hi @Hi_there! Do you still have this problem?